# How can I give my paid users a more responsive app than my free users in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Anyone have an idea on how to achieve a differentiated service with Google App Engine? I have two types of users. One is premium while another one is free user. I would like to set different minimum latencies for firing up new GAE instances between the two. In other words, I am willing to pay extra for the traffic generated from the premium users. Nonetheless, for the free users, I would prefer to pay at minimum or within the daily free quota provided by Google. In my case, I expect that the free users are able to tolerate higher latency than the premium ones. I believe that this case should be quite general and apply to many people.

Assuming that I can identify types of users by the URLs they use or via other mechanisms. The only way I could think of is creating two separated applications and letting the premium users access the one that enables billing, while free users access the one that doesn't. However, my free and premium users need to share the datastore because they are also have to communicate within the application. Unfortunately, it seems that sharing a datastore across applications without hurting performance is not possible at the moment.

Comment: I've been pondering the exact same question, with a slightly different twist - how do I serve free users with F1 instances and paid with F4. There is a feature request to allow GAE apps to share the datastore, which would address this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300 Please vote for this!

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to do to your users. Could you not offer less storage/less requests or ad supported content for non-premium? By offering slow service to your non-premium users you'd possibly lose the opportunity to convert them into paying customers, because they'd leave your service.

Comment: Yes, I could. However, the most important quality in my case is the latency. As a result, it's more compelling for the users to convert if lower latency is the target.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible right now. App Engine gives you a few knobs to balance cost vs. response time: instance class (applies to all versions), min/max pending latency, and min/max idle instances. The latter two sets of knobs only apply to the default version of your app.

There are other ways you can try to lower cost for free users though. e.g. give them limited storage, limit the number of logins or page views over a period of time, serve them lower quality images (if your app is image intensive), etc.

I'm not sure "cut costs for free users" is a useful strategy though. The conventional wisdom is that you want to turn your free users into paying customers (known as "conversion" in the biz). This is more or less what App Engine itself tries to do :P. There is no magic bullet that instantly turns free users into paying customers. The "trick" (if you can call it that) is to make the paid version of your app so compelling that people would rather part with their money in order to have it.